# Analytic integration of this function

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate \begin{equation}
\int{\frac{1}{(1-\frac{a}{r}-b r^2)}} \, \mathrm{d}r
\end{equation}

where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Considering $$\begin{equation}
I=\int{\frac{d r}{1-\frac{a}{r}-b r^2}}=-\int{\frac{r}{b r^3-r +a}}\,dr
\end{equation}$$ Let $x,y,z$ be the roots of $b r^3-r +a=0$ so $$b r^3-r -a=b(r-x)(r-y)(r-z)$$ and $$I=-\frac 1 b \int \frac{r}{(r-x)(r-y)(r-z)}\,dr$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition followed by integration of each term would lead to a sum of logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int{\frac{rd r}{ (r-a-b r^3) }} $$

Solve $r-a-b r^3=0$ for $r$.

You find the roots, real or complex, $r_1 , r_2 , r_3$

Hense :

$$r-a-b r^3=-b(r-r_1)(r-r_2)(r-r_3)$$

$$\int{\frac{rd r}{ (r-a-b r^3) }} = -\frac{1}{b} \int{\frac{rd r}{ (r-r_1)(r-r_2)(r-r_3) }} $$

$$\frac{1}{ (r-r_1)(r-r_2)(r-r_3) }  = \frac{r_1}{ (r-r_1)(r_1-r_2)(r_1-r_3) } + \frac{r_2}{ (r-r_2)(r_2-r_1)(r_2-r_3) } + \frac{r_3}{ (r-r_3)(r_3-r_1)(r_3-r_2) }$$

$$\int{\frac{rd r}{ (r-a-b r^3) }} = -\frac{1}{b} \left( \frac{r_1 \ln(r-r_1) }{ (r_1-r_2)(r_1-r_3) } + \frac{r_2 \ln(r-r_2)}{ (r_2-r_1)(r_2-r_3) } + \frac{r_3 \ln(r-r_3)}{ (r_3-r_1)(r_3-r_2) } \right)+C$$

Note : While I was typing, Claude Leibovici gave the answer. Cheers !

Comment: Few minutes too late ! Cheers :-)